# Target Value updates in Debug but not in Inspector during Gameplay

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, path-finding, game-development

I have a piece of code which once it is triggered the AI Destination Setter target changes to a New Destination. My problem is that in the Debug it changes the Destination but in the Inspector during Gameplay when the object is triggered the Target wont change. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Could you add the code for the `AIDestinationSetter` class please?

Comment: Yes no problem. Added code

Comment: Hmm and what exactly does a `VersionedMonoBehaviour`? Does this come from [here](https://arongranberg.com/astar/documentation/dev_4_1_0_5e02b42b/class_pathfinding_1_1_versioned_mono_behaviour.php)? Maybe you should rather contact the Support of the makers of those classses

Comment: In the inspector you mean the `target` value or the `IAstarAI.destination`? Is there maybe a custom editor script for that component which prevents changes in playmode?

Comment: Im referring to the target of the AI Destination Setter

Comment: Yes im using the A* Pathfinding which is a predefined code

Comment: sounds like a heisenbug. you must have some multithreaded messagepump that is marshalling the calls into your above code. in debug they have enough time to complete, during gameplay they don't. try printlining

Comment: What is printlining? would this solve my problem?